# Maven Artifact with Jar inside

Tags: java, maven

I have the jar file outer.jar which contains inner.jar which contains classA I depend on.

I have transformed outer.jar to an Maven artifact with mvn:deploy:deploy-file and added it to a local repository to use in pom.xml as dependency. The artifcat is added successfully.

But classA from inner.jar is still not found in Eclipse. I get that Eclipse only findes inner.jar in the artifact, which is useless for Eclipse. Any way to use ClassA with Maven without repacking outer.jar?

Comment: Having a jar inside a jar will not work cause [Java JAR's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html) are not defined that way. The classA which is inside the inner.jar which is packaged into outer.jar will never being found cause that's not the way to go here. The question is: Why have package the inner.jar insider a outer jar?

Comment: outer.jar comes from an Eclipse OSGi project and has a META-INF inside.

Comment: An OSGi bundle can not be used as usual dependency in particular in relationship with classpath. Apart from that that information was not part of your question. If you like to use those things as usual dependency (via classpath) you have to migrate them to usual project (no jar within another jar). To let the be usable within OSGi they need a appropriate manifest...